# Does the sentence "I read a book yesterday " mean that the book was finished?

Tags: past-simple

Let's say I ask someone ***what did you do yesterday*** and they answer with ***I read a book yesterday***. Does that mean they read the book till the end? If so, then how do I say that I read a book, but I didn't finish it?

Comment: If the book is unfinished (or was started on a previous day) you can say "I was reading a book yesterday."

Comment: @Weather Vane Can "I was reading a book yesterday" be used by itself, without something else happening at the same time?

Comment: @anouk you can say "I was reading a book yesterday." But if there was no preceding question such as "What were you doing yesterday?" and no follow-up like "...so I forgot to go shopping" there wouldn't be much point. People would look at you as much as to say "So?"

Comment: @Weather Vane So it is not necessary that something else is happening at the same time like: "I was reading a book yesterday when the phone rang"?

Comment: It isn't *necessary*, it is a grammatically correct sentence but on it's own doesn't mean much. As I wrote, what would be the point of saying "I was reading a book yesterday" with nothing else forming a conversation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have asked this question too and you will probably get different answers. As far as I know "I read a book yesterday" means you read the entire book. You could say: "I did some reading yesterday", "I read a book for a while, an hour, etc." or "I read a few pages or chapters", something like that. I prefer "I did some reading".